# Can non-certified Sitecore developer become Sitecore MVP?

Tags: training-certification, mvp

Can a non-certified Sitecore developer become Sitecore MVP? Is it requires the latest Sitecore 10 certification, if so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Certification is not necessary to become a Sitecore MVP.

Answer (score 0):

To become MVP you only need to do contribution in community. No certification is needed to become Sitecore MVP.